# MVC form post model list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, list, post, model

I have a Model that gets sent to a view. This model has List elements that are used to populate listboxes. In this view, I post to a controller action passing in my model as a parameter. On postback, I can see primitive types, but, can't seem to access the list. Here's my code:

Model:

```
public class ReportInfoViewModel
    {
        public int report_id { get; set; } = 0;
        public string report_name { get; set; } = "";
        public string report_path { get; set; } = "";
        public string plaza_param { get; set; } = "y";

        public List<FacilityViewModel> facilitieslist { get; set; } = new List<FacilityViewModel>();
}
public class FacilityViewModel
    {
        public string facility_id { get; set; }
        public string facility_name { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model CSC.ViewModels.ReportInfoViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewReport", "Reports", Model, FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_blank" }))
{
if (@Model.plaza_param.ToString().ToLower().Equals("y"))
    {
    @Html.DevExpress().ListBox(
        l =>
        {
            l.Name = "lstPlazaParam";
            l.Width = Unit.Pixel(300);
            l.Height = Unit.Pixel(120);
            l.Properties.SelectionMode = ListEditSelectionMode.CheckColumn;
            l.Properties.EnableSelectAll = true;
            l.Properties.TextField = "facility_name";
            l.Properties.ValueField = "facility_id";
            l.SelectedIndex = 0;
            l.Properties.ValueType = typeof(string);
            l.Properties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
            l.Properties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.ErrorText = "Please select a Plaza";
            l.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorText = l.Properties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.ErrorText;
            l.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorTextPosition = ErrorTextPosition.Bottom;
            l.Properties.ValidationSettings.Display = Display.Dynamic;
            l.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.ImageWithText;
        }).BindList(Model.facilitieslist).GetHtml();
        ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine("<br />");
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ViewReport(ReportInfoViewModel _model)
{
    string _parameterList = "";
    ReportViewerViewModel _rptObj = new ReportViewerViewModel();

    if (_model.plaza_param.ToLower().Equals("y"))
    {                
        string[] _selected = DevExpress.Web.Mvc.ListBoxExtension.GetSelectedValues<string>("lstPlazaParam");                
        string subParam = "plazaparam=";

        subParam += String.Join(",", _selected);
        _parameterList = string.Concat(_parameterList, "@", subParam);
        _parameterList = string.Concat(_parameterList, "@usrplazaparam=", getSelectedPlazaDisplayValues(_model.facilitieslist, _selected));**//here, _model.facilitieslist is null**

    }
    return View("AfterView", _rptObj);
}
```

What I am trying to do is on post back, send the model back to the controller. All primitive types are sent back, except the list types. How do I send back a list model on post? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a hidden field in my view serializing the list and storing it in the hidden field.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewReport", "Reports", Model, FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_blank" }))
{
    string facilitiesListJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model.facilitieslist);
    @Html.Hidden("FacilitiesList", facilitiesListJson);

//other form objects
}
```

In my controller action, I deserialized the hidden field(Request.Form) and access the list.

```
string _jsonString = Request.Form["FacilitiesList"];
                List<FacilityViewModel> _objList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FacilityViewModel>>(_jsonString);
```